# DateTime.Parse() works in wcf service hosted in console app but not in a windows service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

For example, the following line of code

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse("07/14/2014 3:42:51 PM");
```

What I would expect to happen is that the following string "07/14/2014 3:42:51 PM" would be converted into a valid DateTime.
This line of code runs fine within the WCF service when hosted on a console app, yet it does not when the console app is installed as a windows service with the error:

```
"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.".
```

I can't seem to find any mention of this, is this known problem? or is it more likely a quirk of my code. If I did not supply all the code needed please ask for any specific parts.

Comment: Was there an error message?

Comment: Check the culture settings of the computer. That's almost always the problem.

Comment: Is the date string hard coded like that in the service?

Comment: @Chris No, just put that there as an example, I'm pretty sure it is a culture problem as I have had to mess with it on previous projects so that could have caused something. But I figured why send the string to the wcf when I could just send the DateTime and let the DataContract deal with parsing it. Don't know why I was doing it the other way.